# Is there any way to list all .pkg packages that I have installed?

Tags: install, macos, pkg

Just wondering if there is any Terminal command to do this, because I think my OSX was already messed up with some incompatible .pkg installations.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package management system used by OS X is rudimentary when compared to Linux counterparts like [RPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager) or [DEB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_package). Fortunately, basic operations like listing packages and its contents are possible:

Everytime a `.pkg` file is installed a [BOM](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/bom.5.html) file is stored in `/private/var/db/receipts/`. You can either do `ls` in that directory or use `pkgutil` to list installed packages:

```
$ pkgutil --packages
(...)
com.apple.pkg.HP_Scan
com.apple.pkg.HP_Scan3
com.apple.pkg.HP_SmartX
com.apple.pkg.InstallMacOSX
com.apple.pkg.JavaEssentials
com.apple.pkg.JavaForMacOSX107
com.apple.pkg.JavaMDNS
com.apple.pkg.JavaSecurity
com.apple.pkg.JavaTools
com.apple.pkg.MBP91
com.apple.pkg.MediaFiles
com.apple.pkg.MobileDevice
com.apple.pkg.MobileDeviceDevelopment
com.apple.pkg.OxfordDictionaries
(...)
```

To query the `.pkg` file's contents use `pkgutil`:

```
$ pkgutil --files com.apple.pkg.Pages4 | less
Applications
Applications/Pages.app
Applications/Pages.app/Contents
Applications/Pages.app/Contents/CodeResources
Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks
Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/Inventor.framework
Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/Inventor.framework/Inventor
```

or `lsbom`:

```
$ lsbom /private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.Pages4.bom | less
.   40775   0/0
./Applications  40775   0/80
./Applications/Pages.app    40755   0/0
./Applications/Pages.app/Contents   40755   0/0
./Applications/Pages.app/Contents/CodeResources 120755  0/0 28  2941952436  _CodeSignature/CodeResources
./Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks    40755   0/0
./Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/Inventor.framework 40755   0/0
(...)
```

See [man pkgutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgutil.1.html) and [man lsbom](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsbom.8.html) for other options.