# Is there any way to get a log of all the recently installed files and their respective folder paths and source directories?

Tags: macos, finder, mojave, path, pkg

I recently installed an open source game. The file type is .pkg .

Now, during installation the installer asked for permission to access the system UI server. I didn't knew the reason behind it so I googled it up and before I could deny it the dialogue box asking for the permission has disappeared.

The installation was successful. But, I don't know where did the installer installed the game I tried every app cleaner to find the installed file but couldn't find it, it's not even in the applications folder.

So my question is; is there any way to get a log of all the recently installed files and their respective folder paths and source directories, so that I can find it and delete it?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: macOS and the game is a tycoon themed transportation management game

Comment: Which one?  El Capitan?  High Sierra?  Mojave?

Comment: Mojave; I have included that in the tag, it's Mojave thus macOS is asking for each and every permission

Comment: Then there's pretty much only two places it can install software:  `/usr/local/...` or your home directory `/Users/<username>/...`

Comment: I searched in the home directory; no results, let me check the local directory once

Comment: You could examine the installer package with something like "Suspicious Package" https://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/

Comment: An answer from the "Related" section: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105614/is-there-any-way-to-list-all-pkg-packages-that-i-have-installed?rq=1

Comment: I also play OpenTTD. First just spotlight search for OpenTTD. Rerun the installer .pkg there may be an uninstall option.

Comment: I second the recommendation to check out Suspicious Package: https://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/ It’s actually the default app for .pkg files on my Mac. Also, if you tell us where to download the game, we might be able to help more by looking at the actual .pkg file.

Comment: @TJLuoma SP didn't find any installable files but, it was able to export the installation scripts the pkg is destined to run

Answer (score 1):

Installers that ask for your login password can put a lot of crap in your filesystem.

You could create a user account in the future with standard credentials, not admin, purely for games. This maintains a separation and improves security.

But for now let's explore a bit.

To see the files created after a specific date, like when you installed the game, use *find* from a Terminal like

```
find / -type f -newerct 2018-01-01
```

Or whatever date you want. You can find files of a certain size, whatever, find is powerful but slow. It will, however check the entire filesystem if necessary. Replacing the slash with the tilde (~) constrains searches to your home folder. Some searches need to be run with *sudo.* Try *man* *find* from a Terminal.

You should also set up *folder actions.* on key folders. I do this on all of my machines via right click on

/Library/LaunchAgents
/System/Library/LaunchAgents
/Users/*username*/Library/LaunchAgents

To be alerted if installers drop files there in the future. There are corresponding LaunchDaemon folders alongside them.

When running a legitimate package .pkg installer you can generally do a Get Info (⌘I) to see a list of what will be installed.

Comment: after the search accomplishes how am I supposed to search for game related files installed previously among the thousand other search results the command outputs

Comment: Well you know it isn't easy, what you want to do. There's ways to check filesystem changes that happen after a point easier than what was created in the past. Going forward this is best planned out. If you remember the install date you search a range of times like an hour or two, plenty of *find* tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Mojave but on High Sierra keeps good record of Installed Applications.

Go to About this Mac > System Report

scroll down to Software ad click on Applications

if you found it select it and it will show you where it is

Comment: It's not in the application menu but when I selected the installations menu it showed the file but not it's path

Comment: Are we talking about Online PC game ?

Comment: Nope it's not an online pc game

Comment: give me the link so I can check it out

Comment: here's the link https://mega.nz/#!lgVXVSzK!MBptB7s4qIKRRTiBMP2bPWjLQ-QMqUvmdTJ4HZmzIOM